# Html Entity decode method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am Making an editor like fiddle and I am stuck in early phase. My javascript built-in functions are not working.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="hello">
    <p>here is a paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>
<div class="hello123">
    <a href="#" onclick="myFunction();">Click here!</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
function myFunction(){
    alert('u r here');
}
```

when I post this form to preview my template containing html and javascript. Everything seems to be working fine, but javascript does not work when I click inspect element to see my code in browser, the javascript function is vanished and instead of this `<a href="#" onclick="myFunction">Click here!</a>`
I get like `<a href="#">Click here!</a>` onclick method vanished.
I am using html_entities_decode method while posting my html in controller. I am using codeigniter framework.

Comment: This must have something to do with Codeigniter sanitizing the post data. Could you show how you are retrieving the post data in your code?

Comment: $data = array(
    "user_id" => $user_id,
    'template_name'=>$this->input->post('template-name'),
    'template_type'=>$this->input->post('template_type'),
    'wp_tmp_html'=>htmlentities($this->input->post('wp-html-code')),
     'wp_tmp_css'=>htmlentities($this->input->post('wp-css-code')),
     'wp_tmp_js'=>htmlentities($this->input->post('wp-js-code'))
  ); this is the data array how i am posting to controller

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ***;*** character on your onclick..copy this code below

```
<div class="hello">
    <p>here is a paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>
<div class="hello123">
      <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Click here!</a>
</div>
```